# Google Script Web App HTML Logging Issues

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm learning how to use Google Web App and am following this YouTube video Google Sheets Web App Example - Google Apps Script Web App Tutorial - Part 1 and I am really enjoying the series. It is very easy to follow along with the videos. But I am running into a little issue with the first video. For some reason when I try to do log the button click on the HTML page, nothing happens. I sure it's going to be something silly. But I have been at this now for a few hours and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
  
}

function userClicked(name){
  Logger.log(name + " & noah clicked it!");
}
```

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="username">
    <button id="btn">Run It!</button>
    
    
    <script>
    
    document.getElementByID("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
    
    function doStuff(){
    
    var uname document.getElementByID("username").value;
    
        google.script.run.userClicked(uname);
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me there is something silly that I am just not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your script of HTML side is not correct. By this, the script is not run. So I think that `Logger.log` is not run. Please modify your script of HTML side as follows and test it again.

#### Modification points:

- `getElementByID` is `getElementById`.
- `var uname document.getElementByID("username").value;` is `var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
<script>

document.getElementByID("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);

function doStuff(){

var uname document.getElementByID("username").value;

    google.script.run.userClicked(uname);
}

</script>
```

To:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);  // Modified

function doStuff(){
  var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;  // Modified
  google.script.run.userClicked(uname);
}
</script>
```

- By this modification, you can see the log at Apps Script Dashboard.

#### IMPORTANT:

- In your case, when you access to the Web Apps using your browser by logging in to your Google account, the log can be seen. But if you want to access to a script and curl, please include the access token to the request header. By this, the log can be seen. Please be careful this.
- When you cannot include the access token to the request header, in that case, please link the Google Apps Script project to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project. By this, the log can be seen at Apps Script Dashboard.

#### References:

- [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [Apps Script Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard)

Comment: yes I found the 2 mistakes you pointed out to me but it is only logging to the executions google apps script dashboard, how do I get it to log window in the script editor under view--Logs

Comment: @Aaron Dolgin Thank you for replying. When Web Apps is used, when the script is run by requesting to the Web Apps, unfortunately, the log cannot be seen at "View" -> "Logs". In this case, please open "Apps Script Dashboard" from "View" -> "Logs". It seems that this is the current specification. In this case, the result is the same even when the Google Apps Script project is linked to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project. I apologize for this.

Comment: Interesting, Google must have changed this recently as this video was posted in Jan 2019.

Comment: @Aaron Dolgin Thank you for replying. At February 7, 2020, V8 runtime has been released. I thought that this might be affected to this situation. But in the current stage, I apologize that I cannot achieve your goal, that you want to see the log at "View" -> "Logs" when access to the Web Apps, by the solution and workaround.